# How does the Python setter decorator work

Tags: python, decorator

I am just starting Python, so bear with me if I am missing something obvious. I have read about the decorators and how they work, and I am trying to understand how this gets translated:

```
class SomeObject(object):

    @property
    def test(self):
        return "some value"

    @test.setter   
    def test(self, value):
        print(value)
```

From what I have read, this should be turned into:

```
class SomeObject(object):

    def test(self):
        return "some value"

    test = property(test)

    def test(self, value):
        print(value)

    test = test.setter(test)
```

However when I try this, I get

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'setter'
```

Can someone explain how the translation works in that case?

Comment: I understand that, but in order to use decorators properly, you first need to understand how they work. (when I say "should", I'm talking about the runtime)

Comment: That's fine, just thought I'd make sure you were doing this for *educational* reasons, not because you thought it was a good idea in general code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're getting that `AttributeError` is that `def test` re-defines `test` in the scope of the class. Function definitions in classes are in no way special.

Your example would work like this

```
class SomeObject(object):

    def get_test(self):
        return "some value"

    def set_test(self, value):
        print(value)

    test = property(get_test)
    test = test.setter(set_test)
    # OR
    test = property(get_test, set_test)
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Bonus question, why doesn't this work when I call it on an object?

obj.test = obj.test.setter(obj.set_test)

Comment: Because descriptors only work when set on the class. During attribute retrieval, Python will check for descriptors on the class and call them if they exist. Another example is bound methods.`SomeObject.get_test` is your original function which takes one argument, but `someinstance.get_test is` is a bound method which takes no arguments. It curries ("freezes") someinstance as the first argument.